# Countdown Clock With Years

Tags: python

Currently working on making a countdown clock that takes a future date and continuously returns the amount of time until that date. However, I can't seem to figure out how to create a condition in which the loop will close once the timer drops below 0. My current code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def clock():
    print ('Please enter a date and time in the format dd,mm,yyyy,hour,minute,second')
    response = input() #intake date and time
    respolist = response.split(',') #split into 5 individual items
    while True:
        try:
            print (datetime(int(respolist[2]), int(respolist[1]), int(respolist[0]), int(respolist[3]), int(respolist[4]), int(respolist[5])) - datetime.now())
            time.sleep(1)
            if #timer runs below 0:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('Something was wrong with the date entered, please try again.')
            clock()
clock()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable with the remaining time and check it when seconds are less than 0 so the final countdown script would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def clock():
    print ('Please enter a date and time in the format dd,mm,yyyy,hour,minute,second')
    response = input() #intake date and time
    respolist = response.split(',') #split into 5 individual items
    while True:
        try:
            remaining_time=datetime(int(respolist[2]), int(respolist[1]), int(respolist[0]), int(respolist[3]), int(respolist[4]), int(respolist[5])) - datetime.now()
            print (remaining_time)
            time.sleep(1)
            if remaining_time.seconds <= 0:
                print ('CONGRATS !')
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('Something was wrong with the date entered, please try again.')
            clock()
clock()
```

Comment: That worked thank you! I had been trying to do the same thing but with days, which apparently is different to input